# Is it possible for Ubuntu to work with MTK6572 Dual Core ARM Cortex A7 family CPU@1.2GHz processor in a tablet?

Tags: tablet, arm

Is it possible for Ubuntu to work with MTK6572 Dual Core ARM Cortex A7 family CPU@1.2GHz  processor in a tablet? As far as my research has gotten me I've found that this cpu is x86 but I'm not entirely sure if that's the only thing I need to be looking for. I'm a newby to the whole tablet scene so if you have any advice as to what other tablet hardware aspects I should be planning ahead for other than the requirements posted by Ubuntu it would be greatly appreciated.

If you do find a good answer can you post the link where you found this info? It would expand my research capabilities and eliminate my need to ask these questions in the future as I came up pretty dry on the google haha.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question. In your title you say it's ARM which means it's ARM not x86.

There are ARM compatible versions of Ubuntu, but you can't just go installing them on any device as their support abilities are currently limited and it's difficult for end users to do. You can find out more about ARM and Ubuntu here, but there isn't much:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM
- http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/arm

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

You say that your processor is an ARM processor, but then you say that it's x86. It's impossible for it to be <del>either</del> both - you'll need to figure out which one it actually is.

That being said, there is an initiative for Ubuntu on tablets and phones, see the following links:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/phone
- http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet